# Jupyter Dashboards: Complex Layout and cell affecting display in different cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use Jupyter dashboard layout to position widgets on the side, while the main chart suppose to be generated in the center and most likely in a different cell (see screenshot attached).
Since I don't have good control over placement of IPython Widgets, I was trying to create this layout by positioning different jupyter cells.

Is there a way to modify widgets in one cell that would trigger updates in another cell? Or is there a better way to build such a dashboard using Jupyter dashboards? [image]

Comment: I'm after something very similar! Have you found a solution?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677772/widget-to-control-multiple-cells-for-jupyter-dashboard